# Access Arraylist using Log.d

Tags: android, jackson

This  is my json file:

```
    [
    {
      "names": "Kent",
      "age": "43"
    },
    {
      "names": "Winnie",
      "age": "41"
    },
  {
    "names": "Jane",
    "age": "41"
  }
  ]
```

And this is my code in array:

```
 List<STUDENT> student = Arrays.asList(mapper.readValue(jsonFile, STUDENT[].class));
```

How do I use log.d to access the names and age?

Thanks.

Comment: Once you have the List of student objects ready, why don't you use a loop with Log.d to print whatever you need?

Comment: First, maybe you just want to put a breakpoint and see what inside the array? Maximum you could done debug searching with ALT + F8.
Second, Have you tried `Log.d(student.get(0).getName());`, I mean Log is a logging class, not data accesor, so exact same as you send the 'student' to a view you shall send to the Log.

Comment: @Remy's comment is illustrated below in my answer. It is best to just set breakpoints and debug in that way to check the values rather than using Log.d. Log.d is useful for maintaining log records in case something breaks and you don't know where it was and want to trace it without having breakpoints everywhere. Or, another example adding verbose output when running a program

Answer (score 0):

Has your STUDENT class overridden toString()? If not, thats the first step:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "STUDENT{names='" + names + "', age=" + age + "}";
}
```

Then in your calling code:

```
 List<STUDENT> students = Arrays.asList(mapper.readValue(jsonFile, STUDENT[].class));
 Log.d(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), students.toString());
```

The toString() method on List will iterate over each STUDENT object and call the toString() method implemented in the STUDENT class.

Answer (score 0):

Place breakpoints next to the lines that you want to check the values of each STUDENT object in your List by clicking left of the line number in Android Studio / IntelliJ / Eclipse.

Next, run the app on your device VIA debug by clicking the bug button instead of just a normally run device (how you put it on your phone). Now, when you reach the breakpoint, further execution of the app will delay and you can monitor variables and values in the console that is on the IDE.

Let me know if that makes sense

Here is a ref link: http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-studio.html